# белая рамка вокруг картинки в css

Tags: html, css

http://findaroom.cloudapp.net/#/ верстка не моя, но меня озадачила рамка, которая появляется у пользователя на аватарке после регистрации (на скрине я убрал у аватарке border-radius для наглядности):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вообще не могу понять, что за рамка такая. Уже все стили убирал даже

Comment: 1. По ссылке я не смог найти свою аватарку, регистрироваться не хочу. 2. По фотографии не видно что там у вас в стилях. Попытаюсь задействовать экстросенсорные способности - у вас в одном из файлов стилей, таки, есть добавление рамки, но, делается это "глобально", либо по тегу. Если вы прошлись только по картинке - есть вероятность что рамка может быть на родительском слое, в котором лежит картинка, или на родителе родителя и т.д.

Comment: Идеальный вариант - если вы дадите тестовые учётные данные. Без них ответить вам по существу будет очень сложно...

Comment: @test123 там есть фейсбук О_о

Comment: @test123 мне пароль от фейсбука сказать?

Comment: @Nikolay , если вам лень создать там аккаунт через какой-нибудь 10minutesmail, почему вы думаете, что другим не будет лень там регистрироваться?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я думаю, что все из-за того, что тег img не имеет аттрибута src:
[image: img without src]

В таком случае, а так же в том случае, если src ссылается на невалидный ресурс, появляется такая рамка.

```css
body { background: black; }
```

```html
<img id="myImg" style="width:42px; height:42px;">
```

Comment: действительно, в этом и была проблема